# unity cardboard camera rendering around object

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm using unity 5.2.2 for this project and CardboardMain prefab. I want to rotate and spin around an object such as the mask example from google cardboard app. As far as I know there are two ways of doing this: 
1. Render the CardboardMain (parent of the Head) 
2. Render the main object.

I'm new to this technology. Would you please help me with C# or JavaScript code and instruction how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: You dont render the head as it has no renderer component, and you pretty much HAVE to render the object you want to rotate if you want to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the CardboardMain object at the same location as the object you are viewing.  Set the Z component of the Main Camera (child of CardboardHead) to a negative value.  You can do this in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Extra tips: Go and study about [Occlusion Culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) in Unity, make your app to be more performance efficient. :D